# React render appending rather than replacing content

Tags: reactjs

I have a `contentEditable` react component that updates based on various state changes. The state item contains the paragraphs within the textbox. These are React components. Below is an example state value for 3 paragraphs.

[image]

The corresponding textbox might look like:

[image]

The conversion to a React component happens on a button click. I have some strange behavior when I update the `HTML` state item with a new paragraph. It appends the new paragraph again rather than replacing: It should always output what is contained in `html` state item.

[image]

It appears like I now have 5 paragraph components in state. but I don't, I should only see the four items as you can see below:

[image]

My render method is just a map through the HTML items in the state. It is a little difficult to explain but hopefully, it makes sense. I'm thinking its something to do with how React is comparing the components?

**Relevant Code**:

```js
// Method to update state with new HTML components
componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
  if (prevProps.isSubmitted !== this.props.isSubmitted) {
    this.handleStateUpdate({
      html: this.createHtml()
    });
  }
};

// createHTML function is something like this, I have excluded unimportant code
createHtml = () =>
  this.props.paragraphDict.map((paragraph, key) => {
    const flaggedWords = Object.keys(paragraph);
    return (
      <Paragraph key={key}>
        {flaggedWords.map(wordId => (
          <Word key={wordId} {...props} />
        ))}
      </Paragraph>
    );
  });

// Render
render = () => {
  const { html } = this.state;

  return (
    <StyledEditor
      ref={this.el}
      contentEditable={true}
      suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
      spellCheck={false}
      onBlur={({ target }) => this.handleEditorBlur(target.innerHTML)}
    >
      {html && html.map(item => item)}
    </StyledEditor>
  );
};
```

Comment: done. There are lots of other pieces to this, but I think this is the relevant logic.

Comment: `if (prevProps.isSubmitted !== isSubmitted)` -- do you mean `if (prevProps.isSubmitted !== this.props.isSubmitted)`? Or is `isSubmitted` defined somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry yes I do. I removed that part by mistake. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not related to the keys. To solve this problem I essentially a added a conditional element based on the current submitting state. This would then correctly re-render the editable field with the new content like so:

```
return isSubmitting ? (
    <StyledEditor />
    ) : (
    <StyledEditor
        ref={this.el}
        contentEditable={true}
        suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
        spellCheck={false}
        onInput={({ target }) => this.handleEditorBlur(target.innerHTML)}
    >
        {html}
    </StyledEditor>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have posted this as a comment but I can't so instead I'll ask here - can you confirm something about the following:

```
createHtml = () =>
  this.props.paragraphDict.map((paragraph, key) => {
    const flaggedWords = Object.keys(paragraph);
    return (
      <Paragraph key={key}>
        {flaggedWords.map(wordId => (
          <Word key={wordId} {...props} />
        ))}
      </Paragraph>
    );
  });
```

`this.props.paragraphDict` : is that an array? The name suggest it is not, but the map suggest it is. Maybe it was meant to be named `paragraphDicts`?

I'm assuming it is an array, in which case `key` would be the index for each item in that array. You are passing this index as a key to your `Paragraph` component, which might be the cause of your issue.

Can you try replacing the `key={key}` with something like `key={paragraph.id}`? (or any other unique identifier for that paragraph)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are are right it is an array. I have excluded quite a bit so its not super understandable. The key is unique, this logic works correctly. The console log images are what this function actually generates.

Comment: Yes the key is unique, as I said, here you are using the index as a key, which is not recommended - here are a couple of articles that explain why:
- https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318
- https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c

I'm not 100% sure that's the issue, but clearly there is a discrepancy between what you are seeing in the DOM and what's stored in your variable/state - and that key here is the only thing I can spot in your code that looks slightly 'off' :)